# Populate dropdown menu from an XML file jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to populate a dropdown menu options from an XML file.
I've searched on Stackoverflow, but the solutions I've found are not working. Here's my jQuery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "signatures.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml
    });

    function parseXml(xml) {
        var select = $('#Bname');
            $(xml).find('Signature').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).find($(this).name).text();
                select.append(""+title+"");
            });
            select.children(":first").text("Please make a selection").attr("selected",true);

        $("#Bname").on("change", function() {
            var filter = $(this).find(":selected").text();
            var $node = $(xml).find("Signature[name='" + filter + "']");
            $("#nom").val($node.find("Nom").text());
            $("#titre-1").val($node.find("PG-Ligne1").text());
            $("#titre-2").val($node.find("PG-Ligne2").text());
            $("#titre-3").val($node.find("PG-Ligne3").text());
            $("#titre-4").val($node.find("PG-Ligne4").text());
            $("#ligne1").val($node.find("PD-Ligne1").text());
            $("#ligne2").val($node.find("PD-Ligne2").text());
            $("#ligne3").val($node.find("PD-Ligne3").text());
            $("#ligne4").val($node.find("PD-Ligne4").text());
            $("#ligne5").val($node.find("PD-Ligne5").text());
            $("#ligne6").val($node.find("PD-Ligne6").text());
            $("#ligne7").val($node.find("PD-Ligne7").text());

        });
    }

});

</script>
```

Here's a sample of my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SignaturesNovatech>
  <Signature name="M-A L">
    <Nom>asd</Nom>
    <PG-Ligne1>Representative</PG-Ligne1>
    <PG-Ligne2>Cleaner</PG-Ligne2>
    <PG-Ligne3>3223 Metro street</PG-Ligne3>
    <PG-Ligne4>1-438-234-4453</PG-Ligne4>
    <PD-Ligne1>www.website.com</PD-Ligne1>
    <PD-Ligne2>mal@website.com</PD-Ligne2>
    <PD-Ligne3>City here</PD-Ligne3>
    <PD-Ligne4>Postal code</PD-Ligne4>
    <PD-Ligne5>Services available</PD-Ligne5>
    <PD-Ligne6>Graphic</PD-Ligne6>
  </Signature>
<Signature name="Alain P">
    <Nom>asd</Nom>
    <PG-Ligne1>Representative</PG-Ligne1>
    <PG-Ligne2>Cleaner</PG-Ligne2>
    <PG-Ligne3>3223 Metro street</PG-Ligne3>
    <PG-Ligne4>1-438-234-4453</PG-Ligne4>
    <PD-Ligne1>www.website.com</PD-Ligne1>
    <PD-Ligne2>mal@website.com</PD-Ligne2>
    <PD-Ligne3>City here</PD-Ligne3>
    <PD-Ligne4>Postal code</PD-Ligne4>
    <PD-Ligne5>Services available</PD-Ligne5>
    <PD-Ligne6>None</PD-Ligne6>
  </Signature>
</SignaturesNovatech>
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I want the name attribute of each "Signature" section of the XML file to appear as an option in the dropdown menu.

Anyone? Thanks a lot

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you should use `attr()` to get the attributes of the node. `find()` is used to retrieve child elements. Secondly, when adding items to a `select` they must be added as `option` elements - not just a string value. Try this:

```js
function parseXml(xml) {
    var $select = $('#Bname');

    $('<option />', { text: 'Please make a selection' }).appendTo($select);

    $(xml).find('Signature').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).attr('name');
        $('<option />', { text: title, value: title }).appendTo($select);
    });

    $select.on("change", function() {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        var $node = $(xml).find("Signature[name='" + filter + "']");

        $("#nom").val($node.find("Nom").text());
        $("#titre-1").val($node.find("PG-Ligne1").text());
        $("#titre-2").val($node.find("PG-Ligne2").text());
        $("#titre-3").val($node.find("PG-Ligne3").text());
        $("#titre-4").val($node.find("PG-Ligne4").text());
        $("#ligne1").val($node.find("PD-Ligne1").text());
        $("#ligne2").val($node.find("PD-Ligne2").text());
        $("#ligne3").val($node.find("PD-Ligne3").text());
        $("#ligne4").val($node.find("PD-Ligne4").text());
        $("#ligne5").val($node.find("PD-Ligne5").text());
        $("#ligne6").val($node.find("PD-Ligne6").text());
        $("#ligne7").val($node.find("PD-Ligne7").text());
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Rory, Thanks a lot. Seems to be almost working. It gives me a long list of blank options, except the "Please make a selection" one. Any idea why?

Comment: Given you're parsing XML, try using `attr()` instead of `prop()`. I updated my answer for you.

Comment: Awesome. It's working now. Thanks a lot! Everythings clearer now. Many thanks